# Sharepoint Drag option

Tags: sharepoint-online, slider

I am just trying to implement in this way instead of radio buttons. Please see the snapshot attached below and let me know is it possible to implement? If Yes, how can I implement this?

[image]

Comment: where have you seen this? Probably its a custom form like PowerApps or SPFx.

Comment: I need to create in a share point list like that above instead off radio button.

Comment: you cant create it with OOTB funcions

Comment: How do i create because i am seeing only radio button and drop down option only.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use jQuery slider to implement the slider thing. Refer this link for more information - [Slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps)

To get values on slider and save values in list, use list api.